# Youtube API get the current search term?

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to get a JSON List of Videos. My Problem is that I can´t get the current Searchresult. If I go on youtube I get different Searchresult as if I run my python Script. I ask because I recognize that there is no such term handled in Stackoverflow.

Code:

```
def getVideo():
    parameters = {"part": "snippet",
              "maxResults": 5,
              "order": "relevance",
              "pageToken": "",
              "publishedAfter": None,
              "publishedBefore": None,
              "q": "",
              "key": api_key,
              "type": "video",
              }
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search"
    parameters["q"] = "Shroud"
    page = requests.request(method="get", url=url, params=parameters)
    j_results = json.loads(page.text)
    print(page.text)
    #print(j_results)
getVideo()
```

I have some thoughts. I think its because of the variables `publishedAfter` and `publishedbefore` but I dont know how I can fix it.

Best Regards

Cren1993

Answer (score 1):

[Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

> Returns a collection of search results that match the query parameters specified in the API request. By default, a search result set identifies matching video, channel, and playlist resources, but you can also configure queries to only retrieve a specific type of resource.

No were in there does it mention that the search results for the YouTube api will return the exact same results as the YouTube Website.  They are different systems.  The API is for use by third party developers like yourself.   The YouTube website is controlled by Google and probably contained extra search features that google has not exposed to third party developers either because they cant or they dont want to.